# Buy Two sub domain SSL Certificates from different SSL providers for same main domain

Tags: tls

I would like to know, is it possible to buy a sub domain SSL cert from different provider if other sub domains SSL  are already registered with another provider for example GoDaddy. Forexample I have following sub domains from Godaddy
server1.example.com
server2.example.com

Now my server1.example.com SSL is expiring soon and I want to buy this subdoamin SSL from different provider. Is it possible

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is nothing preventing you from doing that. As long as you can prove you own the site, you can get a certificate from any provider. You can even have multiple valid certificates at the same time, from different providers, for the same domain or subdomain.